# Optimized option for getting text from a web page

Tags: java, url

I used url.openConnection() to get text from a webpage
but i got time delay in execution while i tried it in loops
i also tried httpUrl.disconnect().
but the change is not that much...
can anyone give me a better option for this 
i used the following code for this

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    URL google = new URL(array[i]);//array of links 
    HttpURLConnection yc =(HttpURLConnection)google.openConnection(); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream())); 
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        source=source.concat(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    yc.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
 
    
URL google = new URL("http://www.123newyear.com/2011/calendars/"); 
HttpURLConnection yc =(HttpURLConnection)google.openConnection(); 
BufferedReader in=newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream())); 
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
 source=source.concat(inputLine);
}
in.close();
yc.disconnect(); }

Comment: I took the liberty of adding your code to the question to improve readability. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I am new here,will be better the next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues I can see.

in.readLine() doesn't retain the newline so when you use concat, all the newlines have been removed.

Using concat in a loop like this builds a longer and longer String.  This will get slower and slower with each line you add.

Instead you might find [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) useful.

```
URL google = new URL("123newyear.com/2011/calendars/");
String text = IOUtils.toString(google.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Reading Directly from a URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) for details on how to to get a stream from which you can read the contents of the URL.

Basically, you

1. Create a url `URL url = new URL("123newyear.com/2011/calendars/";`
2. Call openstream() on the URL object

   ```
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
   ```
3. Read from the stream (like you did).